# Ion Toggle não fica salvo - Storage (ionic)

Tags: android, ionic, toggle, storage

Olá, tenho um problema simples. Possuo uma lista de Toggles no meu app. Preciso que quando os usuários marquem ou desmarquem o Toggle, as alterações fiquem salvas após o aplicativo ser fechado. Estou usando o StorageModule.

Usei este código para adicionar o Storage:

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage`

Depois, fiz as inclusões em meu `app.module.ts`

Esse é meu HTML:

`<ion-toggle  slot="end" color="secondary" [(ngModel)]="Ativar" (ionChange)="Toggle1()"></ion-toggle>`

Esse é meu TS:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

export class Tab1Page {
 
 public Ativar : boolean;



 constructor(public alert: AlertController, public navCtrl: NavController, private storage: Storage) { }

 async Toggle1() {
     if(this.Ativar == true){
       this.storage.set('ativar', true);
     }
     if(this.Ativar == false){
       this.storage.set('ativar', false);
     }
     this.storage.get('ativar').then((data) => {
       this.Ativar = data;
   });
   };
```

Uso o emulador de aplicativos para rodar o app no meu celular:

`ionic cordova run android`

Quando faço alterações no Toggle e fecho o aplicativo, ao abri-lo, as alterações não ficam salvas.
Estou a muito tempo preso nessa etapa. Alguém pode me ajudar? Estou perdido

Answer (score 0):

Amigo você está setando os valores no storage, mas ao abrir o aplicativo você precisa fazer o get para obter o resultado salvo, no caso ao iniciar o app.

Vi que você fez o get no método Toggle1, mas você não deve chamar esse método ao iniciar o app, faça separado esse get e coloque ao em um OnInit.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, mas não funcionou. Pode me ajudar?

`ngOnInit() {
    this.storage.get('Ativar').then((data) => {
      this.Ativar = data;
    }); 
    this.storage.get('Ativar2').then((data) => {
      this.Ativar2 = data;
   }); 
   this.storage.get('Ativar3').then((data) => {
    this.Ativar3 = data;
   }); 
  this.storage.get('Ativar4').then((data) => {
    this.Ativar4 = data;
   }); 

  };`